# How to insert a column to an existing table?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

My table name `userdetails`

I want to insert a new column `mob` after `location` column.

I tried using the code

```
alter table userdetails 
add mob varchar2(10) after location;
```

but its showing error

> ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option

Please help me.

I am using oracle10g.

Comment: you can use this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391280/how-to-insert-a-column-in-a-specific-position-in-oracle-without-dropping-and-rec

Comment: yea,but from google search i got this code,Showing error

Comment: You cannot create a new column *after* a given column - new columns are always added to the end of the table. Also: in a relational database, the sequence of the columns is absolutely irrelevant anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try   get rid of the "after"

```
alter table userdetails add ( mob varchar2(10) )
```

Comment: no,i want to add mob column after the column location.This will create  the column in last

Comment: Oracle only allows columns to be added to the end of an existing table. u can see non standart method here http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_add_a_column_to_the_middle_of_a_table

Comment: Thank you for the link,in MySQL only the  syntax is valid,thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no "after location". The syntax not valid.

You might go the following route:
Just add the mob varchar to userdetails.
It will be added at the end of the table.
And you can still query it.
ALTER TABLE userdetails ADD (mob varchar2(10))

To get the table structure you want:

```
// 1) rename the table
rename userdetails to userdetails_old;

// 2) recreate the table with your wanted structure
// Note that the selection order decides about the table structure.
create table userdetails
as
select a as a
     , b as b
     , location as location
     , mob  as mob
     , c as c
from userdetails_old;

// 3) check what you did
desc userdetails;

// 4) before dropping your old table
drop table userdetails_old;
```